# How do you join several columns from one entity to single column in a separate entity?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to make a meal scheduling database for a weight loss clinic's customers. These are some recipes:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+
| recipe_ID | recipe_name           |
+-----------+-----------------------+
|         1 | Healthy Burritos      |
|         2 | Stuffed Peppers       |
|         3 | Breakfast Pizza Slice |
+-----------+-----------------------+
```

This is a plan for a day:

```
+--------+-----------+-------+--------+
| ddp_ID | breakfast | lunch | dinner |
+--------+-----------+-------+--------+
|      1 |         3 |     1 |      2 |
+--------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

Each number in breakfast, lunch and dinner in a plan is a foreign key referring to a recipe's ID. I want to perform a query that will get the names of each recipe to display for the user. This is what I've got, but I'm getting the following error that I can't seem to work around: ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'daily_diet_plan'

```
SELECT 
recipe.recipe_name 
FROM 
recipe 
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan ON (daily_diet_plan.breakfast = recipe.recipe_ID)
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan ON (daily_diet_plan.lunch = recipe.recipe_ID) 
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan ON (daily_diet_plan.dinner = recipe.recipe_ID);
```

Thank you so much for any help you can provide!! I really appreciate it.

EDIT: This works!

```
SELECT recipe.recipe_name 
FROM recipe 
LEFT JOIN daily_diet_plan as brkfast ON (brkfast.breakfast = recipe.recipe_ID) 
LEFT JOIN daily_diet_plan as lunch ON (lunch.lunch = recipe.recipe_ID) 
LEFT JOIN daily_diet_plan as dinner ON (dinner.dinner = recipe.recipe_ID) order by recipe.recipe_name;
```

Comment: Did you consider normalizing your table to avoid the triple join?

Comment: [Link to ERD](http://i.imgur.com/f4qNIa4.png) What revisions would you suggest to this ERD?

Comment: Normalizing three meals for seven days will result in: **weekly_diet_plan** (WDP_ID PK, additional columns?) and

**daily_diet_plan** (WDP_ID FK references (WDP.WDP_ID),
day_of_week byteint check (day_of_week in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) / * Monday to Sunday (enumeration?) * /,
meal_of_day  byteint check(time_of_day in (1,2,3) / * breakfast/lunch/dinner (enumeration?) * /,
recipe FK references (recipes.recipe_ID),
PK (WPD_ID,day_of_week,meal_of_day))     And you might easily add a *tea-time*

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a little hard to understand but when I drew out the ERD, I see it the structure you suggested. If it's not too much trouble, can you point out specifically what was wrong in my old ERD and what type of dependency it was? My professor had approved the project to work on and I don't think I quite get what was unnormalized about my original ERD. Once again, thank you so much. This is all really fascinating material and I appreciate you helping me learn. :)

Comment: IMHO you violated 1st NF, there are repeating groups of day names and meal names.

Comment: Thanks again, I have revised my project as you suggested. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query(I have added diff alias:

```
SELECT 
recipe.recipe_name 
FROM 
recipe 
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan as brkfast ON (brkfast.breakfast = recipe.recipe_ID)
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan as lunch ON (lunch.lunch = recipe.recipe_ID) 
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan as dinner ON (dinner.dinner = recipe.recipe_ID);
```

Comment: While this does not have an error, it returns an empty set. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: instead of Inner join use Left join

Comment: I have one more question. Is there any way to sort it by the order of columns? The result given is Burritos, Peppers, Breakfast slice... but in order of what you're eating that day, I would like the list to say Breakfast Slice, Burritos, Peppers. I don't really know how to say order by column 2, column 3, then column 4 from table daily_diet_plan

Comment: SELECT 
recipe.recipe_name 
FROM 
recipe 
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan as brkfast ON (brkfast.breakfast = recipe.recipe_ID)
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan as lunch ON (lunch.lunch = recipe.recipe_ID) 
INNER JOIN daily_diet_plan as dinner ON (dinner.dinner = recipe.recipe_ID) order by recipe.recipe_name;